# iOS and xcode: how to give a segue a "storyboard id" so that I can programmatically manipulate it

Tags: ios, xcode, modal-dialog, segue

I am wanting to create a modal segue from a view controller to an a new view, but not by linking the segue action to a button or anything. Instead, I'd like to just set the segue up so that I can call it in pageDidLoad and have it automatically execute if I want.

To do this, I need to be able to reference the segue, such as this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender: ...];
```

After I control-click-drag a connection in storyboard to create a segue, how can I give it a name for later reference? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link the segue action from curent viewController to new view controller. I think this you want, see the screenshot.

[image]

This [link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-apps/using-modal-storyboard-segues-iphone-programming/) will help you for remaining code.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind! In the details pane sidebar of xcode, under the third tab there is an "Identifier" field that can be filled out!