# how to set (make) a UIButton at bottom of my UITableview?

Tags: ios, uibutton, tableview

[image]  i have two  Viewcontroller. one with tableview,check button, add button at bottom . i just adjust my tableview up and kept my add button at bottom. when user press my add button it will take to next viewcontroller ( **i did these thing via storyboard** )

**Needed:**

I need my add button should be  bottom to above my table view.when user scroll down my table view  also it should stick at centre of my tableview.i have tried with creating seperate view ,but no use can't do that.Here this is my viewcontroller.m file:

Thanks in advance !

I used storyboard ,so i did iboutlet and synthesis it,

```
@interface ViewController ()



@property (strong) NSMutableArray *notes;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize addButton;
```

**my viewdidload:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Notes";

    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
   }
```

when my add button presses it will move to another viewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    AddNoteViewController *addNoteVC = [AddNoteViewController new];




    // to remove unused warning....
#pragma unused (addNoteVC)

}
```

Like this i need but in centre ....

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do

Comment: What do you mean by "when user scroll down my table view also it should stick at centre of my tableview" and "Like this i need but in centre"?

Comment: Seems like you just want a button on top of your table view, add it to your storyboard but make sure it's not inside the table view, and higher in the view hierarchy so it is not obscured by the table view.

Comment: in above example image add button in left .i need it in centre.at above of my table view (i.e hierarchy view)

Comment: please see this link https://camo.githubusercontent.com/eb4b9d9cc51e30254b575cd5b388ad57d0a4bace/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f7968344d7743422e676966

Comment: like this i need my button in centre.when user scroll down my add button should be as it is?

Comment: did u understand what is my problem @peter

Comment: That's going to get complicated, you'll need to add it to your table view's scroll view, and you're going to have to set your view controller as the scroll view delegate. You will probably have to override scrollViewDidScroll and change the frame of your action button based on where the current content offset is.

Comment: if that's not possible. Then just adding a uibutton(bottom ) to tableview is possible...like above image

Comment: Do you want the UIButton to hover over the tableview or just appear as the user scrolls to the bottom?

Comment: want that uibutton to hover over only....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put buttons over UITableView which won't scroll with table in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689805/how-to-put-buttons-over-uitableview-which-wont-scroll-with-table-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the `UIButton` to **hover** over your `UITableView` the solution should be quite easy.

I just created a `UIButton` which could the one you using.

in your method where you initialise the UIButton (e.g. `viewDidLoad`)

```
    yourBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [yourBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourIMG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    yourBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height -150, buttonwidth, buttonheight);
    yourBtn.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height -155);
    [yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:yourBtn];
```

If this shouldn't be your solution feel free to comment this answer!

### Edit

To set the width and buttonheight just add the following. Write it above the `yourBtn.frame` line!

```
CGFloat buttonwidth = 57.5;
CGFloat buttonheight = 57.5;
```

### Edit 2.0

You need to set the segues identifier first in IB. Check: [iOS and xcode: how to give a segue a "storyboard id" so that I can programmatically manipulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433120/ios-and-xcode-how-to-give-a-segue-a-storyboard-id-so-that-i-can-programmatica)

```
-(IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:yourSegue sender:self];
}
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks will check out this....but getting error in this two line:                                   addBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height -150, buttonwidth, buttonheight);   error:    ` use undeclared  identifier buttonwidth, button height`

Comment: yeah, that's correct!! I added those to let you customize the size of the button. Just replace both with the desired sizes of the buttom you want.

Comment: @ masterRazer yes , thanks its working....hoe  to perform segue for this button....

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of frame setting in @MasterRazer's answer you should edit or add `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` of your `UIButton` in IB. Setting that constraint of your button to 0 would make your button stays in the middle and be a clean and good solution for your problem.

Comment: I didn't say btn.center can't be considered as a good solution, setting frame of the button could be considered as bad solution. Using autolayout with UI components will give you flexibilty about resizing and orientation changes. For this particular problem your solution can work but considering full cycle of development I don't think this is a perfect answer. @MasterRazer